# How to set static ip on Hyper-V vm when host has one network card?

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I am running Hyper-V on Windows 10 and created an Ubuntu server VM.

There is a single network adapter on the VM that is connected to the Default Switch. When I reboot the VM it frequently gets a new IP address.

How can I configure the VM so that the IP always remains the same?

Comment: reboot? i get a different IP address every time i wake it up!

Answer (score 4):

1. Assign static IP inside a Hyper-V VM.
2. Bind VM's MAC address to IP on your router that runs DHCP. Probably it is a wireless physical router connected to your Windows 10 host.

Comment: Better to create an external switch that picks only one interface.

Answer (score 2):

You assign an IP address to a virtual machine the same as you do for a physical machine. Either via DHCP or manual configuration. If you don't want to use DHCP then manually configure the IP address settings in the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to create custom internal (NAT) switch, which i think doesnt have DHCP capabilities by default.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network

Comment: Or just SET the static IP - all of which is as trivial as it gets.